# The will of an old man

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

I found this in one of my books. Enjoy!

A lawyer got the following will (forget the form, I don't know how a will really looks and I tried to translate from my language):

> I, John Smith, of the City of London, England, 2 years after the First World War, at the age of 45, being of sound mind and disposing memory, do hereby make, publish and declare this to be my last Will and Testament.
>
> I do hereby declare, that the beneficiaries of my properties, estates and my assets are my eldest son and his descendants, in case of my death.
>
> Sgd. on 21st of May, 1920 by John Smith.

The will was given by the eldest son of John Smith in 1960, when his father died at the age of 85. However, the will was rejected by the lawyer. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Before World War II, it wasn't called the "First World War".

Comment: That was quite fast! I will not post easy questions again:) (I need to wait five more minutes before accepting)

Comment: The first mentions of the "First World War" predate 1920, even though it wasn't the most common term.